# logstash email Grok pattern

Tags: logging, logstash, logstash-grok

I'm using logstash v7.9.2. i've used nlog in my .net core project for create logs.
and i logged user email in log file. the log format is look like this.

```
<variable name="ExceptionLayout" value="${aspnet-request-url:IncludeHost=true:IncludePort=true:IncludeQueryString=true} ${aspnet-request-method} ${event-properties:item=UserId} ${event-properties:item=Email} ${event-properties:item=UserName} ${exception:format=tostring,Stacktrace}"/>
<variable name="CommonLayout" value="${longdate} [${processid}] ${uppercase:${level}} ${logger:shortName=true} ${aspnet-Request-Ip} ${message} ${onexception:inner=${ExceptionLayout}}"/>
```

and log example like this

> 021-02-13 11:08:22.6739 [20880] ERROR GroupController 10.10.3.241 Found Duplicate Group 'ty'. http://bhavin:12100/Groups POST 14390b07-9407-4abb-9504-34eb02d504c1 bhavin.v@gurukul.org AA2580 FinanceAPI.Execptions.InvalidDataException: Found Duplicate Group 'ty'.
> at FinanceAPI.Controllers.GroupController.Insert(Group group) in D:\Git\finance.api\FinanceAPI\Controllers\GroupController.cs:line 49    at FinanceAPI.Controllers.GroupController.Insert(Group group) in D:\Git\finance.api\FinanceAPI\Controllers\GroupController.cs:line 49

i'm trying this grok pattern for the above log.

```
"%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:Time} \[%{INT:ProcessId}]\ %{LOGLEVEL:Level} %{DATA:Logger} %{IPV4:ClientIp} %{URI:RequestUrl} %{WORD:RequestMethod} %{USER:UserID} %{EMAILADDRESS:Email} %{GREEDYDATA:Message}"
```

but it can't work.what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `%{DATA}` between %{IPV4:ClientIp} and %{URI:RequestUrl} in order to match `Found Duplicate Group 'ty'.`.